# How filter simple multidimensional array with only numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a multidimensional array like this: 
`let arr = [ [1,2,3], [3,4,6], [4,5,7], [8,9,3]];`

and I need to use only a filter function for filtering this array. I must filter the array and create a new array from the current inner arrays which contain the number 3:

```js
let myArr = [ [1,2,3], [3,4,6], [4,5,7], [8,9,3]];
function getVal(value, arr){    
    for(let i in arr){
        for(let j in arr[i]){
            if(arr[i][j] == value){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

}

let newArr = myArr.filter(getVal(3, myArr));
```

My code is not working. Actually, it's working, but I don`t see any result.

The expected result is like this:

`newArr = [[1,2,3], [3,4,6], [8,9,3]];`

All I have found are filter methods with objects.

Answer (score 3):

You need a different style of the callback.

```js
const contains = v => a => a.includes(v);

var array = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 6], [4, 5, 7], [8, 9, 3]],
    result = array.filter(contains(3));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is 2 dimensional array. Use indexOf to check inside arrays:

```
myArr.filter((a)=> { return a.indexOf(3)>=0})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cont result = arr.filter(a => a.includes(3));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.